# unique handler in C++

Tags: c++

I want to create a class, which will provide static method to create unique handler (migth be int, might float, might be something but always retrived as a pointer to object), but im still bit confused in my considerations, and when i started to read about singleton and factory pattern, then im confused at all.

Suppose i have a class

```
CHandle{
private:
        CHandle(const CHandle &hnd);
        CHandle &operator=(const CHandle &hnd);
        static int id;
public:
        static CHandle *createHandle(){
            id++;
            return this;
        }
}
```

in main i would use:

```
CHandle *c = CHandle::createHandle();
```

Can i do like that ? Or maybe Im messing up everything ?

Comment: static methods have no knowledge of `this`

Comment: You could also have used the Search option:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern

Comment: Nooooooooooooooo! Do not use a singleton, they are evil! There are better ways to do this. Constructors and templates for starters. Why do you want to do this, or rather, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: i want to have a mechanism, which can wrap different data type (like int, struct or whatever) and will return pointer to new unique object - like each time method createHanlde() will be called, a new unique pointer to object with unique id will be returned. Thats why i tought about singleton and a factory method, but then someone told me, that i can just use static method with a counter. But now im thinking  who will destroy that objects ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is two thing :

- First `static` methods have no knowledge of `this`. So no `this` inside `static` methods.
- After you can do something like :

  ```
  CHandle{

  public:
          static CHandle *createHandle(){ 
              s_id++;
              return new CHandle(s_id);
          }
  private:
          CHandle(int id) :
              m_id(id)
          {};

          CHandle(const CHandle &hnd);
          CHandle &operator=(const CHandle &hnd);

          int m_id;         // Id of the instance
          static int s_id;

  };
  ```

And if you want it as a *singleton* :

```
CHandle{

public:
    static CHandle *createHandle(){
        if ( !s_Instance )
        {
            s_id++;
            s_Instance = new CHandle(s_id);
        }
        return s_Instance;
    }
private:
    CHandle(int id) :
        m_id(id)
    {};

    CHandle(const CHandle &hnd);
    CHandle &operator=(const CHandle &hnd);

    int m_id;         // Id of the instance
    static int s_id;
    static CHandle s_Instance;

};
```

don't forget in the .cpp :

```
int CHandle::s_id = 0;
CHandle* CHandle::s_Instance = NULL; // if singleton
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CHandle{
private:
        CHandle(int id): m_id(id) {};
        CHandle(const CHandle &hnd);
        CHandle &operator=(const CHandle &hnd);
        int m_id;
        static int s_id;
public:
        static CHandle *createHandle(){
            s_id++;
            return new CHandle(s_id);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always remember that `this` is object related, but `static` is meant for whole class,
so `static` methods can't access `this`.
Here is the help you need

```
CHandle{
private:
        CHandle(const CHandle &hnd);
        CHandle(int iidd);
        CHandle &operator=(const CHandle &hnd);
        static int id;
        static CHandle *obj;//Singleton object
public:
        static CHandle *createHandle(){
            id++;
            return obj;
        }

}
```

And in Project.cpp

```
int CHandle::id=0;
CHandle *CHandle::obj=new CHandle(xxx);
```